# Trying to install Apache Traffic server armhf to raspberry pi

Tags: networking

I have installed Apache Traffic Server into my raspberry pi. But whenever I try starting it i get segmentation error. anyone has any SD images that I can use that already has the Apache Traffic Server installed and running ?

Comment: It would be better if you had posted the Seg fault with any details about how you installed it, version numbers etc.

Comment: sure will do that in a bit.

Comment: so here is the what I get

Comment: when I type "service trafficserver status" into the raspbeery pi then the output is "[FAIL] traffic_server is not running... failed!"